# Finding solution of matrix equation system $XA_iY=B_i$ with respect to $X$ and $Y$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, numerical-optimization

We have matrices $A_i$, $B_i \in\mathbb R^{4\times4}, i \in \{1, \ldots, K\}$ and we'd like to find $X$, $Y \in R^{4\times4}$ such that $X A_i Y = B_i$

Is there any (maybe numeric) way to solve it easily? Number $K$ can be reasonably big i.e. $1$–$100.$

EDIT: I found answer - this problem can be solved as [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) problem.

Comment: Between them $X$ and $Y$ have 32 variables. The matrix equations give rise to $16K$ equations that those variables need to satisfy. Looks like a seriously overdetermined system when $K>2$. Unless there is some special reason to think a solution exists my instincts tell me - no way!

Comment: But, if you want a quick test of solvability, you can wish that $Y$ is invertible, and use the entries of $Y^{-1}$ as variables. The system $XA_i=B_iY^{-1}$ is linear and homogeneous on those 32 unknowns. You need a non-trivial solution, and linear algebra gives you the tools to figure out whether such solutions exist.